# Raspbian: arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find -lm

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, arm, raspbian

I'm building an app on Raspebian (Rpi3b+) using the `gcc-arm-none-eabi` toolchain (which I installed via `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi`).

I successfully compiled my sources, but the linking step:

`arm-none-eabi-ld modes.c.o turing.c.o light.c.o dark.c.o pix.c.o --relocatable -o tlrcextractortest -lm`

fails with:

`arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find -lm`

What could be wrong? Which package do I need to install to get the missing lib?

Comment: Can you include in the question the command used to link the program?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570034/why-does-the-r-option-relocatable-make-ld-not-find-any-libraries why do you use relocatable?

Comment: Also, try `apt-get install libnewlib-arm-none-eabi`.   It looks like the math libraries are part of a recommended package and not a dependency: https://packages.debian.org/sid/gcc-arm-none-eabi.

Comment: Why do you use the `arm-none-eabi` toolchain? The standard GCC for the Raspi _is_ the arm toolchain.

Comment: you have to provide the path to the libraries when using ld

Comment: if you use gcc to link (ewww) then you dont.

Comment: @JonathonS. The lib `libnewlib-arm-none-eabi` I already installed, but it didn't help.

Comment: As @PMF suggested, I've given up on this toolchain, and used standard GCC. Even, still don't know why the `lm` lib was missing.